# Why we should use cache since we have persist in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Q. why should we use cache since we have persist which has memory-only and other options?

this question was asked to me in an interview I don't have any idea about this please help me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cache` is the same as `persist` with the default storage level:

From the [Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/309638eeefbfb13dae8dbded0279bf44390389ee/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L3633):

```scala
/**
 * Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).
 *
 * @group basic
 * @since 1.6.0
 */
def cache(): this.type = persist()
```

So `cache` can bee seen as a convenience function that is widely used.